# Text-overflow ellipsis with file extension

Tags: html, css

I'm making an upload function. I have to display the name of the file just uploaded.

```
File Name.txt
```

But when the name is too long, it shows like this

```
File Name Is Too Long...txt
```

I tried using ellipsis

```
.file-name {
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

But I have no idea about file extension.

Comment: const splits = 'File Name Is Too Long...txt'.split('.');
const `extension` = splits.pop();
const `name` = splits.join('.');  use `extension` and `name` separately.

Comment: @Naren I don't think so, it's getting extension name, but I want to display like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to come up with this using flex:

```css
.filename {
  max-width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.name {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="filename">
  <span class="name">File Name Is Too Long.</span>
  <span class="extension">txt</span>
</div>
<div class="filename">
  <span class="name">This filename is also too long.</span>
  <span class="extension">txt</span>
</div>
```